# How to add all my .net standard library DI dependencies in a project that uses my library without adding them all individually

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I want to be able to do `services.AddMyCustomLibrary()` like Telerik and sweetalert do rather than having to add every service from *MyCustomLibrary* like

```
services.AddSingleton<MyCUstomLibrary.MyService>();
```

What is the code I would add to *MyCustomLibrary* to make this work?

I want this:

```
    builder.Services.AddTelerikBlazor();
    builder.Services.AddSweetAlert2(options => {
        options.Theme = SweetAlertTheme.Bootstrap4;
    });
```

Not this:

```
    builder.Services.AddScoped<ComponentService>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<AppState>();
```

Comment: This is usually achieved by defining an extension method to `IServiceCollection` in your library.

Comment: This is done using extension methods. Cf https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Comment: Thanks @hwoodiwiss you gave me the direction I needed. I tried searching google but couldn't get the right words to find what I needed. Got it all working extending IServiceCollection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create static class with extension method for IServiceCollection. Inside of extension method, you can write your library registrations:

```
public static class Service Collection Extension {
    public static IServiceCollection AddMyCustomLibrary(this IServiceCollection services) {
       services. AddSingleton<MyCUstomLibrary.MyService>();
    } 
}
```

Then usage looks like this:

```
services.AddMyCustomLibrary();
```

Edit: you can create also options action that allows you pass some properties to your libraries.

```
public class MyCustomLibraryOptions {
    public string MyProperty { get; set; } 
} 

public static class Service Collection Extension {
        public static IServiceCollection AddMyCustomLibrary(this IServiceCollection services, Action<MyCustomLibraryOptions> configure) {
    var options = new MyCustomLibraryOptions();
    configure?.Invoke(options);
    var myProp = options.MyProperty; //You can access options after action invocation. 
           services. AddSingleton<MyCUstomLibrary.MyService>();
        } 
    }
```

Usage:

```
services.AddMyCustomLibrary(config => {
    config.MyProperty = "some value";
});
```

Comment: IMHO you shouldn't create `MyCustomLibraryOptions` yourself. Use `services.Configure<MyCustomLibraryOptions>(configure)` as this allows the caller to use the anything from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0 if they want to.

Comment: It depends on the situation. sometimes you need to access options values right after passing them to extension method. For example, to fill configuration of a different library (that also expose extension method with configuration action). But in general - using IOptions pattern is a better approach.